# Why do blocking functions not use 100% CPU?

Tags: while-loop, message-queue, infinite-loop, blocking, nonblocking

Sure, the `while` loop over the function call blocks inside *your* app's scope, but something outside still has to be looping right? Does it finally lead up to some hardware blocking event? How else can the CPU not be pegged at 100%?

Comment: You seem to be confusing a tight spin with the overall concept of blocking. Blocking merely requires that no progress be made. I'm tempted to look in to some Linux source code and post it for you, but I haven't the time nor desire. The quick answer is that when a process makes a blocking call, it is pushed on to a queue and is popped off when the kernel is informed that what we were waiting for is complete and the process can continue work. While this process is in a block queue, other processes are free to execute as normal, provided they also are not on a block queue.

Comment: Additionally, this is not the only mechanism. At times, kernel code uses a very tight spin loop to act as a lock (like what you described above). At these times, the spinlock doesn't last long enough for you to notice the increased CPU usage.

Comment: @SanJacinto But what if I'm while looping over a pure software thing like a Java BlockingQueue? Does this also lead back to the kernel doing something?

Comment: I can't tell you what the JVM does under the hood. I've implemented a similar thing using POSIX semaphores (though there are other constructs, too). While the semaphore is in a blocking state, I believe that the Linux process is placed into a queue, waiting for this semaphore to "awaken."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that the operating system is in charge of the CPU. Your code only gets to run when the operating system calls it.

If you ask the operating system to wait for something, the operating system *won't call your code* until that thing happens.

Imagine the operating system scheduler as a loop like this:

```
while(true)
{
    for(Process *p : all_processes)
    {
        RunSomeCodeInProcess(p);
    }
}
```

This would always use 100% CPU, even if your process wasn't running. But actually, the loop is more like this: (still simplified)

```
while(true)
{
    bool all_processes_blocked = false;
    for(Process *p : all_processes)
    {
        if(!IsProcessBlocked(p))
        {
            all_processes_blocked = false;
            RunSomeCodeInProcess(p);
        }
    }
    if (all_processes_blocked)
    {
        StopCPU();
    }
}
```

The OS will not bother running processes that are blocked. It will skip over your process and only run other processes. If *all* processes are blocked (note: this is normal) then the OS will stop the CPU. When the CPU is stopped, it uses way less power, creates way less heat, and it doesn't execute instructions. That means StopCPU won't return.

... *until* the CPU gets an interrupt from some hardware device, like a mouse saying it got moved. Then the CPU automatically starts up again and runs the interrupt handler. When the interrupt handler returns, it goes back to StopCPU, so StopCPU returns and the OS checks for unblocked processes again. The hardware interrupt probably unblocked one of the processes. For example, if the interrupt was because the computer got a network packet, then now the process that was waiting for the packet is unblocked. If it was because the user pressed a key on the keyboard, then the process that was waiting for the key is unblocked, and so on.

So there are two main advantages to using blocking I/O instead of polling:

- You don't waste CPU time that other processes could get.
- If all processes are blocked (this is *most of the time*!) the CPU can save power and heat.

---

This is also how `sleep` works. There's a hardware timer that counts down and then sends an interrupt. When you do `sleep(1)`, the OS sets the timer to one second, then blocks the process. When the interrupt comes in, it unblocks the process.

There's only one timer, but if more than one process is sleeping, the OS sets the timer to the one that wakes up first, and then when the interrupt comes in, it unblocks the first process and sets the timer for the next one. This technique is called a "timer queue".